# How to get tensorflow log device placement on dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When i use this code tensorflow does not show device placement of my tf.add operator. How to know if this operator is done on GPU or CPU ?

```
import tensorflow as tf

c_0 = tf.constant(0, name="c")

with tf.device("/device:CPU:0"):
    c_1 = tf.constant(51, name="c")

with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
    c_2 = tf.constant(56, name="c")


def add_2(val):
    return tf.add(val, 2)


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([c_0, c_1, c_2])
dataset = dataset.map(add_2)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
get_next = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    print(sess.run(get_next))
    print(sess.run(get_next))
    print(sess.run(get_next))
```

Output is:

```
tensors/component_0: (Pack): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
IteratorToStringHandle: (IteratorToStringHandle): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
IteratorGetNext: (IteratorGetNext): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
c: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
c_1: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
c_2: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
OneShotIterator: (OneShotIterator): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2
53
58
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Dataset API runs on CPU. It won't log ops that are inside dataset object. 
However, you can explicitly map iterator to GPU.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([c_0, c_1, c_2])
dataset = dataset.map(add_2)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.copy_to_device("/gpu:0")).prefetch(1)
```

This will only work with `make_initializable_iterator()` 
Take a look at this links

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19244

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610